# Adding together values of ENUMs

Tags: java, enums

I'm struggling to add together values that I've declared within ENUMS. I basically need to add together values of each card within a hand of cards based on rank.

I've tried a few things but not actually got anywhere. I can display the ENUM's but they have no value.

Here is my code:

**Card Class**

```
 public class Card {

 private Suit suit;
 private Rank rank;
 int totalValue;


 public Card (Suit suit, Rank rank) {
 this.suit = suit;
 this.rank = rank;  
 }

public Suit getSuit(){
return suit;
}

public void setSuit(Suit suit)
{
this.suit = suit;
}

public Rank getRank()
{
return rank;
}

public void setRank(Rank rank)
{
this.rank = rank;
 }


 @Override
 public String toString ( ) { return ( rank + " of " + suit); }

 }
```

**Suit Class**

```
public enum Suit {

HEARTS , SPADES , CLUBS , DIAMONDS 

}
```

**Rank Class**

```
public enum Rank {

ACE(1),
TWO(2),
THREE(3),
FOUR(4),
FIVE(5),
SIX(6),
SEVEN(7),
EIGHT(8),
NINE(9),
TEN(10),
JACK(10),
QUEEN(10),
KING(10);



private int RankValue;


private Rank (int rValue)
{
RankValue = rValue;
}



public int getRankValue()
{
return RankValue;
}

}
```

**Hand Class**

```
public class Hand {



private Card theCards[ ];
private int numCards;
private int totalValue;
private static final int max = 5;
private Rank rank;
private Suit suit;

public Hand ( )
{
 theCards = new Card [max];
 numCards = 0;
}

public void addCard( Card aCard ) 
{ 
     if (numCards < max) theCards[numCards++] = aCard; 
}

public void setRank(Rank rank){

    this.rank = rank;

}

public void setSuit(Suit suit){

    this.suit = suit;
}

public int totalValue() {
int totalValue = 0;
for (Card card : theCards) {
totalValue += card.getRank().getRankValue();

}
return totalValue;

}

@Override
public String toString ( ) 
{
   String s = "Rank: " + rank + "Suit: " + suit; 
   for (int i = 0; i < numCards; ++i)  { 
    s += "\n" + theCards[i] + "\n" + totalValue; 
   }

   return s;
}
}
```

Finally my Hand Driver with the main method

```
public class HandDriver {

public static void main( String[] args ){ 

Hand h1 = new Hand();   

Card c1 = new Card(Suit.valueOf("HEARTS"),Rank.valueOf("TEN"));
Card c2 = new Card(Suit.valueOf("SPADES"),Rank.valueOf("ACE"));
Card c3 = new Card(Suit.valueOf("DIAMONDS"),Rank.valueOf("SEVEN"));
Card c4 = new Card(Suit.valueOf("HEARTS"),Rank.valueOf("NINE"));
Card c5 = new Card(Suit.valueOf("HEARTS"),Rank.valueOf("THREE"));

h1.addCard(c1);
h1.addCard(c2);
h1.addCard(c3);
h1.addCard(c4);
h1.addCard(c5);


System.out.print (h1.toString());


;
} 
}
```

I'm basically looking for someone who is able to point me in the right direction to display the total value of all cards

Comment: Add together as in `+`?

Comment: what is the value of `h1.totalValue()`?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you'd be calling `totalValue() ` to populate the `totalValue` variable which you are using in `toString()`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasnt too clear.  I've created the card objects and put them within my hand array. I now need to add all the values up within the hand and display the total value

Comment: @AnjunaTom see my comment above. Instead of using the variable, try invoking the method itself after your loop: `s += totalValue();`

Comment: Why are you writing things like `Suit.valueOf("HEARTS")` instead of `Suit.HEARTS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Hand class, you are using int totalValue, which is then "shadowed" in your function totalValue(), so totalValue will be zero. Then, in toString() you are using totalValue, which is never calculated. First, remove "int" here:

```
public int totalValue() {
    //removed "int", so you are not declaring local totalValue variable
    //but using your class variable  
    totalValue = 0;
    for (Card card : theCards) {
        totalValue += card.getRank().getRankValue();

    }
    return totalValue;
}
```

Then, in your toString(), call the above function, so that totalValue is calculated, and then you can use it in your loop:

```
@Override
public String toString ( )
{
    String s = "Rank: " + rank + "Suit: " + suit;

    //call totalValue() to calculate totalValue
    totalValue();

    for (int i = 0; i < numCards; ++i)  {
        //now you can use totalValue, because it's been calculated in totalValue()
        s += "\n" + theCards[i] + "\n" + totalValue;
    }

    return s;
}
```

As noticed by Holger, you can also use Suit.HEARTS instead of Suit.valueOf("HEARTS").

**EDIT:** As noticed by Grove, totalValue() doesn't have to be called for every card. Call it before you build your string, and then you can use totalValue variable in your for loop.

Comment: +1 That's almost it because `totalValue()` should be called only once, not for every card. However you might also want to loop only one time through the cards, so perhaps you could calculate the total while building the string to output, instead of calling `totalValue()`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

I agree with "Holger" you should not be using 
`Suit.valueOf("HEARTS")` and 
`Rank.valueOf("TEN")`

Instead it should be

```
Suit.HEARTS
Rank.TEN
```

Then in the Card and Hand classes you should probably be calculating the value of that Card or value of that Hand as the suit and rank is added to the Card and as a Card is added to the Hand, that way when you get the total value of the Hand or want to do toString() you only need to read the value rather than calculate it every time.

In the Hand class the way you are adding a Card to the "theCards" array should be like so:

```
if (numCards < max) { 
   theCards[numCards] = aCard;
   numCards++;
}
```

Then as I mentioned before you should probably in this if block also call another method which you will need to create to update the total value.

Finally, to calculate the total of a Card you may want to do something like,

```
int suitVal = suit.ordinal(); // This returns a number which is the position of the enum value

int rankVal = rank.getRankValue();
totalValue = suitVal + rankVal;
```

I could have just changed all your code and pasted it in here for you but that I think would not be good for learning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if (numCards < max) { 
   theCards[numCards] = aCard;
   numCards++;
} **IS** equivalent to if (numCards < max) { 
   theCards[numCards++] = aCard; }

Comment: Your right it is equivalent. Personally I prefer if statements to not be on one line even if there is only one line of code to perform in it but that's just personal.

Comment: That's fine, if it's your personal opinion, please don't write in your answer: "(...) array **should** be like so: ", because both if statements are equally valid